# How to run Dart "pub get" from inside Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, dart, buildpath, dart-pub

I just downloaded the [Dart Eclipse plugin](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/eclipse-plugin/) and am trying to figure out how to run `pub get` from inside my new project (to resolve dependencies).

1. I installed the plugin via `Help >> Install New Software`
2. I went to `Window >> Preferences >> Dart` and installed the latest SDK
3. Restarted Eclipse
4. I created a new `Java Project` (seeing that I will use Dart/dart2js for all my client code and Java for all my server code)
5. Added a `pubspec.yaml` in a config directory (see below)

I was expecting to be able to right-click my project and see an option like `Dart >> Pub Get`, or `Build Path >> Add Libraries >> Add Dart Pub-Managed Library`, or something obvious. But I'm not seeing anything.

Did I don anything wrong in my steps above? How do I run `pub` from inside my Eclipse project?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't use a lot of the Dart SDK features if you create something other than a **Dart Project** in Eclipse.  Since I created a Java Project, these features were disabled. As soon as I created a Dart Project, if you right-click the project, you'll see a `Dart` menu item that then has several submenu items; one of them is `Pub Get`.

**One more note**: I'm on Linux and had to `chmod`  the `pub` binary that downloaded with the SDK that Eclipse installed for me. Otherwise I was getting `Permission denied` errors when running `Dart >> Pub Get`. Just FYI to future Dartisans.

A little disappointing, but understandable. So it looks like I'll have to have 1 project (Dart Project) for my client-side, and another project (Java Project) for my server-side.